# How to add gradient background to Swift playscene BEHIND all other elements?

Tags: swift

Im building a single view game in Swift, and Ive been trying to add a gradient background to the game.  I have made a new class that handles all the gradient things, but when I add it to the background in the scene, it shows up on top of all the other elements instead of behind where it belongs.

heres what Ive written.  It gets the color values from the separate class that I wrote.

```
let background = CAGradientLayer().turquoiseColor()
background.frame = (self.view?.bounds)!
self.view?.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)
```

Any idea why its adding on top?

Comment: If you want it in back don't you want `atIndex: 0`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot i had changed it. I was messing around with it to see if changing the numbers would do anything, but they dont.  It was originally at 0, and it still wasnt working properly. Im gonna edit the question to show that

Comment: Is this code in your View Controller? If not, where is it?

Comment: @Ike10 This code is in my playscene.swift and gamescene.swift.

Comment: Can you give some reference as to what those are? Does either one inherit from `UIViewController` or act as the View Controller for you "single view"?

Comment: @Ike10 both inherit from SKScene.  I just tried putting the code inside of my GameViewController which inherits from UIViewController but the same problem occured

Comment: Last questions:  How are you adding the other elements? Can you post some of that code?

Comment: @Ike10  all of my sprites and labels are added using this line "self.addChild(self.hero)"  if it helps, "self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF)" when I use this to set the background color, it works as it should, but I need a gradient, which cant be added with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to add it as a sublayer. Render the gradient to an image and set that image as the texture of SKSpriteNode then add that node to your scene For example:

```
     override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let size = CGSize(width: (self.view?.bounds.width)!,height: (self.view?.bounds.height)!)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 1.0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer().turquoiseColor()
        gradient.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size)
        gradient.renderInContext(context!)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        let texture = SKTexture(image:image)
        let node = SKSpriteNode(texture:texture)
        node.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        node.zPosition = -10.0
        self.addChild(node)
    }
```

Comment: Ok so now, this solution presented another problem.  It seems to add it behind the everything, but you cant interact with anything on the screen.  Touches don't register, and I have a sprite that wont show up.  It seems to over take everything thats on the screen for some reason

Comment: So after running it a few times, Ive found that when the game loads, everything runs a lot slower than it usually does.  Not only that, but it loads a different set of sprites each time it runs, and sometimes it loads nothing but the background.

Comment: Think you want to set the `zPosition` of the background node to be a negative value so other sibling nodes will appear in front. There is a performance hit associated with rendering a gradient, but if you're just setting a background it should not be noticeable, and would only occur when that node is created, likely before the scene is even on screen. I would need to see your `touchesBegan` method to know what's going on with your touch detection.

Comment: Which one of these variables is the zPosition? is it the UIGraphicsBegin...Options with the 1.0?

Comment: I updated my answer but `zPosition` is just a property on `SKNode` and any of its subclasses.

Comment: this works as it should except theres still that performance hit.  I know you said its because it has to render a gradient, but should it really make everything feel like its moving through molasses?

Answer (score 0):

```
//1
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.colors = [UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]
gradient.locations = [0, 1]
gradient.frame = sceneView.frame

//2
let background = UIView(frame: sceneView.frame)
background.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

//3
sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

//4
view.insertSubview(background, atIndex: 0)
```

So this solution has four steps:

1. First, you create a `CAGradientLayer` and configure. Make sure to set it's frame to the frame of your Scene View.
2. Next, you instantiate a `UIView` with the frame of your Scene View and add the gradient from Step 1 as a sublayer of the new `UIView`.
3. **Important:** Set the `backgroundColor` property of your Scene View to `UIColor.clearColor()`.
4. Insert the `UIView` from Step 2 at index 0 in your View Controller's `view`.

I am unsure why you can't add the gradient layer to the layer of the Scene View directly, but this seems to work. My theory is that it has to do with how the Scene View is rendered and that all layers may be above the renderings of a Scene View (so even one at index 0 would still be on top).

Note: In my example, the `sceneView` property is an `@IBOutlet` of a Scene View in my Main.storyboard file that I dragged and dropped from the object library into the default Single View Application View Controller. This Code is in the default `ViewController.swift` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: for some reason, this one still diddnt work.  The coment above this one did though, and Im not sure, but I think its because of the .addSublayer.  but thanks for all the help either way!

Comment: @JakimBeaufort If beyowulf's answer worked, which is a much better answer ( I have little to no experience with SceneKit but was trying to help), you should mark it as correct.

Comment: Just did! and thanks for the help, its still appreciated